# Use of would and verbs in past

Tags: spoken-english

I would like to know if this sentence is correct :

> When I was in high school , one of my friends would get a date every single day, all he had to do was just show his wallet.

I don't want a formal English version, just an American common way to say it because I won't actually write it, I will just talk but I want it to make sense.

By the way, can I say "all he **would** do was just show his wallet" too? I don't wan't to change the meaning of what I'm trying to say.

Comment: That sentence is correct, and you could indeed use 'would' as you have suggested.

Comment: @user8543 which one sounds better?

Comment: Neither, they both sound fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is fine and natural. Changing *had to* to *would* is also natural, but it does change the meaning slightly:

- The original, *all he **had to** do* (which might be paraphrased as ‘the only thing he was required to do’) emphasizes that no further effort was necessary.
- The rewrite, *all he **would** do*, loses this particular emphasis—it simply reports the fact that showing his wallet is all he **did** do. In fact, you could also communicate this meaning with a simple past: *...all he **did** was just show his wallet.*

There’s also a possible rewrite in the first clause. In the dialect spoken where ***I*** went to high school, *would* was replaced by *used to* (‘useta’):

> When I was in high school one of my friends used to get a date every single day ...

There’s no difference of meaning or emphasis there, just a dialectal preference for *useta* in contexts like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct and would sound natural in conversation. Changing "had to" to "would" won't change the meaning significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is a run-on sentence. You have two clauses each of which is a complete sentence on its own: "When I was in high school, one of my friends would get a date every single day" and "all he had to do was just show his wallet". Slapping them together like this is called a "comma splice" and is incorrect. You should either break it into two sentences, connect them with a semi-colon, or add a conjunction:

1. When I was in high school, one of my friends would get a date every single day. All he had to do was just show his wallet.
2. When I was in high school, one of my friends would get a date every single day; all he had to do was just show his wallet.
3. When I was in high school, one of my friends would get a date every single day, as all he had to do was just show his wallet.

Of course in spoken language the difference between a comma and a period or semi-colon is hard to identify precisely.

Also, "all he had to do" and "just" is a shade redundant. I'd probably say either "all he had to do was show his wallet" or "he just showed his wallet". But that's getting nit-picky.